# SCSS Input checkbox is checked style

Tags: html, css, sass, less

I'm very grateful if you could help me, i was trying to set styles for 2 elements based on input:checked in my SCSS but isn't work.

```
<div>
<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox'></input>
<label for='checkbox'>Lorem ipsum</label>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>

div {
  user-select: none;
  input {
    &:checked + label {
      background: red;
    }
    &:checked + p {
      display: block;
    }
  }
  p {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/ricardonas/pen/xxZVydJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make the paragraph visible, you need to update the selector. `:checked + label` means "get the label immediately after the checked element". Following this logic, you need to target "the paragraph after the label after the input":

```
div {
  user-select: none;
  input {
    &:checked + label {
      background: red;
    }
    &:checked + label + p {
      display: block;
    }
  }
  p {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

Comment: You are welcome, Ricardo. If this answer works for you, would you accept it?

Comment: You can also use the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Combinators#General_sibling_combinator): `&:checked ~ p`; however, this will select **all** `p` elements that follow the `input:checked` element.